# How to test 14 day timeframe on user creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a trial period checker and I'm trying to test whether a user was created inside the 14 day period. So if its outside 14 days then I get a false. Thoughts?

```
if @user.trial_period === true
trial_users = User.where(created_at:14.days.ago..Time.current.end_of_day)
@trial_check_user = trial_users.where('id = ?', current_user.id)
if @trial_check_user.first.present?
@user_in_trial = true
puts "!!!!!!!    USER STILL IN TRIAL WINDOW   !!!!!!!".red
else
@user_in_trial  = false
puts "!!!!!!!     NOT IN TRIAL NEED SUBCRIPTION   !!!!!!!".red
redirect_to new_subscription_path
end
```

Comment: Are you checking users from the start of the day 14 days ago or from the current time you want to subtract 14 days?

Comment: What's `@user` here? If you had just loaded it from database, you can just check whether `@user.created_at > 14.days.ago`

Comment: Seems like the current_user.created_at > 14.days.ago doesn't always work. It seams to give a false negative. Has anyone had issues with 14.days.ago?

Answer (score 1):

```
if current_user.created_at > 14.days.ago
  # Still in trial
  @trial_check_users = User.where('created_at > ?', 14.days.ago).count
else
  @trial_check = false
  redirect_to new_subscription_path
end
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context explaining how this code will solves the OP's question. Code-only answers are discouraged. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25446602)